# 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' does not contain a definition for 'BackColor'

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I was trying to change the `Background` of a row in `DataGridView` with this code.

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[RowNumber].Clone();
row.Cells[1].Value = "Hey World";
row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
```

But in the third line is this error:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' does not contain a definition for 'BackColor' and no extension method 'BackColor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error because `DataGridViewRow` has no such property.

You could change the `BackColor` for a single row by modifying it's `DefaultCellStyle`:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[2].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
```

You can also subscribe the `DataGridView` to the `CellFormatting` event and place some logic in there to determine which rows need to have a different background color:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
}
```

The above code will change the background color of every other row to gray.

*(This is just a contrived example, since if you actually wanted alternating row colors, you'd change the AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle property.)*